# Is there a need to add waits in between of the script in webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I am writing my first webdriver script in java, the script is working fine but it's very fast.

For eg :- I have textboxes and dropdown elements in my hmtl page and i wrote the script for sending keys and selecting values from the elements but when I execute the script it's very fast is there any need to give implicit waits after every step ? Is it worth ? Or what else is the solution so that the script runs in a smooth way that every step is visible properly.

Below is my code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver wb = new FirefoxDriver();
    wb.manage().window().maximize();
    wb.navigate().to("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

    /*WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(wb, 50);
    WebElement element1 = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.
    elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Mercury Tours']")));*/

    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='REGISTER']")).click();

    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']")).sendKeys("Rameshwari");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='lastName']")).sendKeys("Nayak");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='phone']")).sendKeys("7208471118");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userName']")).sendKeys("Rama");

    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='address1']")).sendKeys("Nithyanand Chawl");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='city']")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='state']")).sendKeys("Maharashtra");
    wb.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='postalCode']")).sendKeys("4000017");

     Select dd = new Select(wb.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name = 'country']")));
     dd.selectByVisibleText("INDIA");   

}
```

Comment: You want your script to run as fast as possible. I would start with no waits and see how it works. You may need to run it 50 times or something to see if you ever have issues. Add waits only as needed and only where needed. For the code you have above, I'm guessing you won't need any waits at all. The times when you might need a wait is when you do something on the page that changes the page content. If you try to interact with the changed content, you will likely need to wait for the content to change before interacting with it.

Comment: If you are wanting to see each step to debug, then place breakpoints and step through the code. You shouldn't want the script to be slower so you can watch the execution and see what's going on.

Comment: @JeffC ohk thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any of below based on your need, but **do not use implicit and explicit waits at the same time.** This will result in inconsistent wait times, and can result in TimeoutExceptions even when you think there should not be any.

**Implicit Wait -**

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

The default setting is 0. Once when we define the implicit wait, it will set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

It will be written once and applied for entire session automatically. It should be applied immediately once we initiate the Webdriver.

Implicit wait will not work all the commands/statements in the application. It will work only for "FindElement" and "FindElements" statements.

If we set implicit wait, find element will not throw an exception if the element is not found in first instance, instead it will poll for the element until the timeout and then proceeds further.

**Explicit Wait -**

You can use explicit wait if you want to wait based on certain condition - like visibilityOfWebElement, ElementToBeClickable etc.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("xyz")));
```

Explicit wait is mostly used when we need to Wait for a specific content/attribute change after performing any action, like when application gives AJAX call to system and get dynamic data and render on UI.

Example: Like there are drop-downs Country and State, based on the country value selected, the values in the state drop-down will change, which will take few seconds of time to get the data based on user selection.

**Fluent Wait -**

Using FluentWait we can define the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check for the condition.

And also the user can configure to ignore specific types of exceptions such as "NoSuchElementExceptions" when searching for an element. NoSuchElement exception is thrown by findElement(By) and findElements(By). When ever it try to find any element it returns the first matching element on the current page else it throws NoSuchElementException - when no matching elements are found.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    //Wait for the condition
                       .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
                         // which to check for the condition with interval of 5 seconds. 
                       .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
                     //Which will ignore the NoSuchElementException
                       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I understood this but my question is can i add waits after every step ?Is that a good scripting ? Like i have 5 textboxes on my page can i add 5 waits after every step so that every step is visible ?

Comment: Yes, if your test needs this wait before the element is visible, it is fine to add this wait before every step. That is, an explicit wait. If you intend to use an implicit wait then it only needs to be set once.

Comment: If you are using implicit wait you just need to add it once in your code. But if you want some condition to be true for the elements you are working (trying to find or enter value, click etc.) you should go for explicit wait or fluent wait. Explicit/fluent waits have to be added for individual elements depending upon the condition you want to be true for that particular element. Hope that helps !!

Answer (score -2):

Giving implicit wait property once in your code is enough, it is applicable to all the statements in your code. 
you need to put wait only in case where you are not able to find an element because of page load. Faster the better from performance point if the script is working as expected.

Comment: Yess that's what, we give implicit wait for finding an element after page load. This script  is working fine without wait but the execution is very fast that i am unable to see every step. So Is there any way or solution that my script runs smoothly so that every step is visible.

Comment: you can use **Thread.sleep(0500);**  after every statement where ever you want to put wait. This will hold the execution for that many milliseconds. like in this it will hold for ''0500'' milli seconds. So you will be able to see the run just fine.

Comment: Is that worth adding thread after every step ? If i have more than 10 steps in my script and I'll add thread after every step it will lengthen my code right ?

Comment: according to my knowledge you can't control run speed, but you can use a work around. You can create a method with return type as WebElement which takes your element with what you need to perform an action and add thread.sleep() in it. this way you don't have to manually add it to your code all the time. For Eg : **WebElement navto(String str)
 {      Thread.sleep(500);
  WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@"+str+"]"));
  return ele;
 } ** //so you can take it up further for any processing or modify the method as per your need

Comment: Why did you delete then repost? Please don't just avoid negative feedback this way; address that feedback directly instead. If you continue to do this, you'll end up blocked from adding more answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Undeleted it and gave my reason. very well noted the seriousness of the issue though. Thank you. Also, I didn't repost it, may be because it was already down voted while i was editing my post it got posted as a new post.

Comment: And now you have two almost identical posts :-) please do delete one; next time better just comment and update the one answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : That was the reason I deleted it the last time. Will try and avoid such situations in future. Not very old on stack overflow. :)

Comment: @RavikarBhardwaj: that's quite alright, I appreciate the constructive responses!